# How to execute a function for every index in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, closures

I have a function (which currently) because of a closure will remember the last index it returned (from an array) on a function call and return the next value from the next index.

```
  function getCurrentValue(values) {
    let index = -1;
    let l = values.length;

    function increment() {
      ++index;
      if (index < l) {
        return values[index];
      } else {
        index = -1;
        ++index;
        return values[index];
      }
    }

    return increment;
  }
```

What I am doing is I'm passing into the function an array of degrees of a circle:

```
  let degree = getCurrentValue([0, 315, 270, 225, 180, 135, 90];

  degree() // returns 0
  degree() // returns 315
```

What i'd like is to pass in another array which is a range of distances of meters:

```
distances = [75, 175, 275, 375, 475];
```

What I want is the current degree value to increment when we have returned have applied each distance to every degree.

```
 let degree = getCurrentValue([0, 315, 270, 225, 180, 135, 90], [75, 175]);
```

So degree should behave like:

```
 degree(); // returns 0;
 degree(); // returns 0;
 degree(); // returns 0;
 degree(); // returns 315;
 degree(); // returns 315;
 degree(); // returns 315;
```

I tried:

```
   function getCurrentValue(values, helper) {
    let index = -1;
    let l = values.length;
    var temp;

    function increment() {
      ++index;
      if (index < l) {
        return values[index]
      } else {
        index = -1;
        ++index;
        return values[index]
      }
    }
    
      if (typeof helper != 'undefined') {
        for (let i = 0; i < helper.length; i++) {
          console.log('temp', temp)
          return temp = values[index];
        }
      }

    return increment;
  }
```

But that didn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

**UPDATE**
Might be helpful to see the context of what this will eventually do:

I have markers I'd like to add to a circle on a map from the center outwards. Thee markers should be laid down along degrees I choose:

```
 function setMarkerToCenterOfSegment(lat, lng, degree, distance) {
    return GeometryUtil.destination(L.latLng(lat, lng), degree(), distance());
  }

  let degree = getCurrentValue([0, 315, 270, 225, 180, 135, 90], [75, 175, 275, 375, 475]);
  let distance = getCurrentValue([75, 175, 275, 375, 475])

 {markers.length && markers.map((marker, index) => {
   return 
    <Marker
     key={index}
     position={setMarkerToCenterOfSegment(...initRadiusForCircle, degree, distance)} />
     }
  )}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*we have gone through each value in the distances*". Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Sorry I thought I was clear with the return value I wanted I'll add more clarification.

Comment: @Bergi Essentially I don't want the degree value to increment, until a marker has been placed for each value in the distance array.

Comment: I don't understand ‘we have returned have applied each distance to every degree’. It looks like `degree` returns the next degree from the array after it's called 3 times, but why 3 times when there are only 2 distances? I'm confused as to how the function is supposed to work.

Comment: Also I feel like this is an overcomplicated way to accomplish what you want — instead of having functions that maintains internal state (`degree` and `distance`), you could use `index` in the `markers.map` function to determine the degree and distance to use. This question is also tagged [tag:functional-programming]; note that this is not strictly functional programming as it involves mutable state and `degree` and `distance` are not pure functions.